# Real Time computation

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, real-time, distributed-computing

I have a algorithm written in python and mysql which takes inputs in csv file and some properties and then run for 20-25 mins to produce output.

I want to make it realtime such that if input csv is upload or and properties is changed the output is changed without need to run algorithm

Note Data on which algorithm runs can be very large.
Need help in making realtime computing algorithm

i am trying to change mysql to nosql DB but it still takes time to run and is not realtime

Comment: How is it real-time? You did not specify any constraints on completion time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using one of the streaming services for event driven update. Instead of CSV, write the data to stream like Kafka or Kinesis. Write your consumer that reads incoming invents and updates the data without running the full algorithm. You might be able to use Apache Flink for aggregation against Kafka as well.